# Why am I getting java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError after upgrading Kafka streams version?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

I have a set of applications that are similar in their structures (all created from a template repository with a uniform structure for a Kafka streams application).
I've upgraded the version of the Kafka streams package from 3.4.0 to 3.6.1 on all of those applications. When I ran them, only two (out of 8) of them failed with the following stack trace:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.rocksdb.DBOptions
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.openDB(RocksDBStore.java:190)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.RocksDBStore.init(RocksDBStore.java:166)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.WrappedStateStore.init(WrappedStateStore.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesStore.init(ChangeLoggingKeyValueBytesStore.java:56)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.WrappedStateStore.init(WrappedStateStore.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.CachingKeyValueStore.init(CachingKeyValueStore.java:113)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.WrappedStateStore.init(WrappedStateStore.java:71)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.lambda$init$3(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:150)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.metrics.StreamsMetricsImpl.maybeMeasureLatency(StreamsMetricsImpl.java:867)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.state.internals.MeteredKeyValueStore.init(MeteredKeyValueStore.java:150)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorStateManager.registerStateStores(ProcessorStateManager.java:219)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StateManagerUtil.registerStateStores(StateManagerUtil.java:102)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.initializeIfNeeded(StreamTask.java:242)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.tryToCompleteRestoration(TaskManager.java:701)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.initializeAndRestorePhase(StreamThread.java:901)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce(StreamThread.java:778)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop(StreamThread.java:617)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run(StreamThread.java:579)
```

All applications use RocksDB the same way, so not only that I don't understand why the `org.rocksdb.DBOptions` class is not found, I also don't understand why it happens only in two of the applications.

What could it be?
How can I further investigate this?

Comment: Did you read the upgrade notes of Kafka streams or RocksDB Java library?

Comment: @OneCricketeer Actually I did, and even tried the two-phase rollout, but I still got the same error (also, IIUC, this issue is not related to the versions I'm working with). Also, it happened only in 2 out of 8 applications, which use RocksDB the same way.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I've checked it more thoroughly - did you see anything in the upgrade notes that made you think it might be related to my issue? AFAIK, rocksdb is part of the Kafka streams bundle (I opened the Jar file, and it contains the rocksdb lib.so files), so there shouldn't be an issue with versions compatibility

Comment: Do you anything overriding `java.io.tmpdir` System property? Maybe it is not writable on all instances? E.g. https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/troubleshoot-ksqldb/#javalangnoclassdeffounderror-when-javaiotmpdir-is-not-writable

Comment: @OneCricketeer Checked our entire codebase on github, no mention of either `java.io.tmpdir` or `ROCKSDB_SHAREDLIB_DIR`. Also, it happens only with version 3.6.1. if I role back to version 3.4.0 it works perfectly.

Comment: @OneCricketeer, also - I found the rocks lib under the /tmp directory inside the containers (/tmp/librocksdbjni960123777873633894.so). I looked at the contents of the application jar file, and I saw the rocksb so file is there - so what's this file doing under temp? I also saw that it is being created after the container is already running

Comment: The so files are for C/C++ bindings of RocksDB. They must be extracted from the JAR file first. But the error is separate from having the so files... Are you able to see `DBOptions.class` in the JAR? (notice the ksql page says `Options` class, not `DBOptions`)  What happens when you try 3.6.0 or 3.5 versions instead?

Comment: @OneCricketeer, tried 3.6.0 - same issue.

Comment: @OneCricketeer Also, I ran tar tf <jar file> | grep DBOptions.class and I did see it (org/rocksdb/DBOptions.class)